# GCR: The possibility to delete images and change tags are gone from the UI

Tags: google-container-registry

Hi since yesterday it is not anymore possible to change the tags or delete images from the UI. I selected one images but can not delete it. I am owner of the project. Over GCLOUD CLI it is possible.

**No Tag change possible:**

[image]

**Delete grey:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue in the Cloud Console UI. [It's already reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144836081).

Comment: ... and by gcloud CLI, we can still delete using: gcloud container images delete [IMAGE]